# JTable entire table data change

Tags: java, jtable

Is there a relatively simple way to change all the data in a JTable? For example, if I have a JTable named books which contains information about all books by a certain author, and then the user changes the author, I would have to update that table with a completely new set of information (note, because of the volume of data in question, it is not practical to use a filter on the table and update the filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using a custom table model, which could call fireTable*** methods (AbstractTableModel) to notify of relevant changes.

Comment: Could you point me to a good How-to tutorial? I've been using the Java tutorials, and it led me to a dead end with this with a similar statement.

Comment: I found the sun book very useful: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Core-Java-Advanced-Features-2/dp/0130927384/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1229224180&sr=1-9

But that was a few years ago and it's quite dry. I'll see if I can find something a bit more accessible.